# `M-x shell` not displaying colors

Tags: shell, colors

**OS**: Mac OS 12.5.1
**Emacs**: GNU Emacs 28.1 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0, NS appkit-1671.60 Version 10.14.6 (Build 18G95)) of 2022-05-11 (i.e. the 28.1-4 binary from https://emacsformacosx.com/)
**Shell**: zsh 5.8.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin21.0)

When using `M-x shell`, terminal colors are not displayed. I do not recall this being a problem in Emacs 27.x; it has only been an issue since I upgraded. I have

```lisp
(require 'ansi-color)
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on)
```

I know that *something* is working because colors appear correctly in `M-x term` (which I am not switching to, for Reasons):

[image: A screenshot with M-x shell on top, showing no color application; and M-x term on bottom, showing color application.]

`echo`ing a string that explicitly contains control sequences for colors still works:

`echo -e '\e[30m██\e[31m██\e[32m██\e[33m██\e[34m██\e[35m██\e[36m██\e[37m██\e[0m'`

[image: M-x shell with the above command executed. Color is present in the command output, but not in the prompt.]

`M-x describe-char` on a character in the prompt shows that `font-lock` is picking up *something*, even if it isn't being rendered:

[image: M-x describe-char output showing a color code in font-lock-face]

However, the same is not true for, say, the `ls` output, which should have directories shown in blue as in the `M-x term` example. (If there were a way to show the raw characters in this buffer I could be sure whether some color codes are being clobbered, but I don't know how to do that.)

[image: M-x describe-char output showing no color-related text properties]

Running `zsh` within `eshell` has the same problem, though I assume that's more a case of `eshell` doing its own rendering that bypasses whatever problems `ansi-color` itself is having.

[image: zsh run within eshell; eshell has coloring on ls but zsh does not]

This shouldn't be related to the GUI; I can reproduce all of the above running `emacs -nw` through a terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because I was using a color theme that defined a `bold` face, probably in some way that broke the way anonymous fonts are handled.

Specifically, `ansi-face-bold` is defined as `((:inherit 'bold))`, and the `font-lock-face` generated by `ansi-color` was `(ansi-face-bold (:foreground "blue2"))`. This works properly if `bold` is not a defined face, but not if `bold` is `((dark (:bold t :foreground "#93a1a1")))`. I have not tested other values of `bold` to see if there are acceptable ones (e.g. I don't know if that `dark` bit at the front is throwing things off).